# How to paginate using Divs instead of Posts?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pagination

I have a simple template page which I just added to my website, and will be manually adding in divisions for a new newsletter every month. However, when I get quite a few newsletters, users who will be viewing the page will have to keep scrolling down to find a newsletter.

```
<?php get_header();?>
<div id="main" class="defaultContentWidth">
<div id="wrapper-row">
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content">
<?php the_breadcrumb();?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <?php if(have_posts()) :
      while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="newscont"><?php the_content();?></div>
      <?php endwhile;
        endif;?>

        <div class="contnewslist">
        <div class="newsblock">
            <h2>NEWSLETTER 1</h2>
            <i>December 01, 2014</i>
            <p>This is the December edition of the newsletter. Featuring in this newsletter is ...</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Download" id="download" class="newsdownload">
        </div>
        <div class="newsblock">
            <h2>NEWSLETTER 2</h2>
            <i>January 01, 2015</i>
            <p>This is the January edition of the newsletter. Featuring in this newsletter is ...</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Download" id="download" class="newsdownload">
        </div>
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Therefore I want to know how I could add basic pagination **'Previous 1 2 Next'** buttons onto the page and limit the amount of divisions of newsletters to about five per page, baring in mind **these are not posts**!

**EDIT 1**

I need to know how to count the amount of divs there are, limit it to five divs per page and generate more pages depending on how many newsletter divs there are!

An example of the sort of paginating I would like is -

[image]

Comment: I see you have wordpress tagged, isn't there a plugin that does this ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Billy I have found a few plugins that offer paginating etc... But to be honest, the ones I have found are based around paginating posts, hence why I stressed that I am not using posts!

Comment: where are the divs coming from  DB or hard coded into html ? if it's DB then there's loads of tutorials on Google

Comment: @Billy They are hard coded into html, but if it is much harder to accomplish pagination using hard code, then I can perhaps look into changing it over to a DB.

Comment: can you add jquery to the page ? javascript pagination would be better depending on how much there is a it saves a round trip to the server. if there is loads and loads then change it to DB and server side pagination is best. google jquery pagination or php pagination

Comment: @Billy Thanks, if you could please explain that in more detail as an answer, then I will mark it as one. Basically, what I need to know is how to count the amount of divs on the page, keep a maximum of five divs per page and generate other pages if there is more than five.

Comment: Do you need true pagination, or does it just need to appear as such? In other words, can you fake the pages within a page, or do you actually need them on their own .html/.php file?

Comment: @slime I suppose they can be faked. The main thing is, I just don't want the user having to scroll endlessly down a page to find a newsletter, therefore, I just want it broken up into 5s.

Comment: Group all your divs inside a container with overflow hidden and whitespace set to no-wrap, then every 5 elements group inside another div which will act as your page. Make these pages inline-blocks that are the same width as the container. Then, you can just animate the blocks left or right depending on what page they need to be on. And then creating the pagination links at the bottom is easy as long as you keep track of what page they're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to go if they are on the DB would be with PHP and Jquery pagination. let's say for example that you have 100 newsletters, you could do it with just php pagination like this tutorial [PHP Tutsplus tutorial on pagination](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928) and split it into 5's, Go this way if the newsletters are large in size. The downside is a call to the server for each page change. If the newsletters are fairly small then mix jquery in, have the php count the total, pass over the first 15 or 20 and have jquery split them up in to 5's, with maybe an ajax call when page 5 is loaded to fetch the next 15.jquery would be able to handle that and add on onclick when page 6 is requested to update the div seemlessly
Jquery pagination pluhgins can be found [here, sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go and get back to you if I need any further assistance!